# Compare Observable's Previous Value With Next Value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, lodash, observable

I have been working on an App that allows a few different components to update a `BehaviorSubject` in Angular. Within each component I store a local copy of the previous `BehaviorSubject` value. In order to know whether or not the component generated the new value being pushed out I was planning on just comparing the two objects using LoDash's `_.isEqual()` function. However I am finding that my local copy of the Observable has already been updated before the comparison can take place.

Does Angular look for `=` statements and create an external binding to that component property outside of the Observable `next` function?

Given the code below I am finding that my `this.QueryParams` property within the component has been updated to the current value being processed in the function, causing my comparison to fail even though I don't assign the new value to the property until the `if` statement has been evaluated.

**Component**

```js
export class LogsModalComponent implements OnInit {

    private QueryParams: LogsQueryParameters

    ngOnInit() {

        this._LogsService.QueryParameters$.subscribe(_QueryParams => {
            console.log(this.QueryParams);
            console.log(_QueryParams);

            if (!_.isEqual(this.QueryParams, _QueryParams) {
                this.QueryParams = _QueryParams;

                // Some code to process if the new value was different.
            }
        }
    }

    updateStartDate() {
        this.QueryParams.filterStartDate = _.isUndefined(this.FilterStartDate) ? NaN : new Date(this.FilterStartDate.nativeElement.value).getTime();
        this._LogsService.updateQueryParams(this.QueryParams);
}
}
```

**Service**

```js
    LogsQueryParameters: BehaviorSubject<LogsQueryParameters> = new BehaviorSubject<LogsQueryParameters>({
            limit: 25,
            logLevels: "",
            logTypes: "",
            logUserIDs: "",
            filterStartDate: NaN,
            filterEndDate: NaN
        })
        LogsQueryParameters$ = this.LogsQueryParameters.asObservable();

    updateQueryParams(QueryParams) {
        this.LogsQueryParameters.next(QueryParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RxJS observables have a method [`distinctUntilChanged()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged) that returns a new observable that only emits a new value if it is different from the previously emitted value:

```
this._LogsService.QueryParameters
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((_QueryParams) => this.QueryParams = _QueryParams);
```

This works for simple comparisons. If you need the `_.isEqual` function nonetheless, you can pass a callback to `distinctUntilChanged()` to perform the comparison instead:

```
this._LogsService.QueryParameters
    .distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => _.isEqual(prev, curr))
    .subscribe((_QueryParams) => this.QueryParams = _QueryParams);
```

Note that you don't return `! ...` inside the callback, whenever the return value is `false` (meaning the value under test *is not equal*), the value *passes*.

**Update**

From your latest edit it looks like you're actually passing around the exact same object, and only mutating its contents, as @Brandon suggested in the comment below. You could try creating a new object when updating, through `Object.assign()`:

```
updateStartDate() {
    this.QueryParams.filterStartDate = _.isUndefined(this.FilterStartDate)
        ? NaN 
        : new Date(this.FilterStartDate.nativeElement.value).getTime();
    this._LogsService.updateQueryParams(Object.assign({}, this.QueryParams));
}
```

*Objects are actually passed by reference.*

Note that `new Date()` also returns you an object. That object is passed and assigned by reference as well, only this time `Object.assign` won't help you out, since the date object depends on prototype linkage (it's not a *plain* object).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, while I am sure I will use that in the future, it doesn't really solve the problem. All the components only emit a new value when they have a new value to emit, but I am attempting to use the compare logic to allow the components to know whether they need to reprocess parts of the model. Essentially I am trying to prevent loops.

Comment: Let me see if the callback method works! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Still not working. Somehow that `this.QueryParams` property is getting updated. But the only place its set to equal anything is within the comparison function, inside the observable subscription.

Comment: Ok, how has `this.QueryParams` been initialized?

Comment: I updated my code in the original post with the service and initialization of `this.QueryParams`.

Comment: This is very weird... And I unfortunately do not have the knowledge to tell you if this relates to how Angular works.

Comment: No problem at all! Thanks for trying Jeffrey, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  Update the Question with code showing how you actually emit a new value into `LogsQueryParameters`.  Based upon your problem description, my guess is that you are mutating the queryParameters object instead of emitting a new object.

Comment: @Brandon I think you might just be right about that!

Comment: I'm afraid not. I updated the post, but this is not an uncommon practice for us to use BehaviorSubjects to share data. I did tinker a bit and found some very strange behavior. If I save the observable output to an Array when a new value comes through a new index is created with the current value, but then all of the objects within the array are updated to the current value as well. Its almost as if the BehaviorSubject's value is being passed as a reference rather than as a value.

Comment: Major Kudos to you guys! We pretty much use strings and numbers exclusively when passing data around. I have run up against this before, but I am surprised it didn't ring a bell! Thank you both!

Comment: Also, the Date object doesn't effect things in this case because of the `.getTime()` function which returns a number.

Comment: yep.  RxJs works best if you code in a functional style.  More specifically, everything works much better if you only pass **immutable** objects through observables.

Answer (score 5):

For those who want to compare the previous value with the current value of an Observable (or BehaviourSubject), just simply use the [pairwise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) operator. Eg:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._logsService.yourObservable$.pipe(pairwise()).subscribe(([previous, current]) => {
        if (previous !== current) {
            // Some code to process if the new value was different.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take account that if you're use pairwise, only executed when has more that one value, so generally you need add startWith `$observable.pipe(startWith(actual_value),pairwise())..)`