# How to return a value using the previous and the current value of a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, behaviorsubject

In my angular app, I have a user service, an activeUser$ behaviorSubject and a loggedIn$ one which will be true or false based(piped(mapped)) on the value of activeUser$.
When **loggedIn$**’s next value is true and then false, that would mean that the user has logged out.
There is a function which I want to trigger only when it is **true and then false**. A loggedOut$ observable as a result would be awesome!
Any idea?

Comment: You should use `pairwise`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66982365/4786273

Comment: Thanks for the link @Random it did help me find the answer I needed in addition to pairwise which is great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer I needed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203449/compare-observables-previous-value-with-next-value-in-angular)

I have implemented it like this:

```
loggedOut$ = this.loggedIn$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((current) => !current)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn more about pairwise operator [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise)

In your case the code would be like this:

```
    loggedOut$ = this.loggedIn$.pipe(
      pairwise(),
      filter(([previous, current]) => previous && !current)
    ).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Just be aware that the subscribe will then contain not a boolean anymore but an array of two booleans per emit (with the previous and the current value)

Comment: you may then map it, to return `void` instead of the array, since the value is not relevent anymore, only the event is.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just found out about distinctUntilChanged https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged . How would you compare it to pairwise? 
  loggedOut$ = this.loggedIn$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((current) => !current)
  );

Comment: @MianalaLoharano distinctUntilChanged allows you to not trigger an event, if it has the same value than the previous one. In your case, this is not what you want to. The filter used in this answer will do the job, so it only triggers an event if the previous value was true, and the current one is false.

Comment: You know better what you need exactly!)